# i keep getting the error message attempt to index nil with "name"

Tags: lua, roblox

i keep getting the error message           (attempt to index nil with "name")  on line 3 of my local script code. does anyone know how to fix this?

this where the error is in the local script

[image: 1]

this is the server script

[image: 2]

I'm new to coding so if I explained bad I'm sorry!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-OAQpxKXz4&list=WL&index=92 (tutorial)

Comment: please post your code in text form not as screen shots

Comment: The error means, that `script.Parent.Parent` is `nil`. What environment is this in? is it roblox?

Comment: yes it's Roblox

Comment: why is  script.Parent.Parent nil

Comment: That would depend, what did you expect it to be? and why do you expect it to be that value rather than `nil`?

Comment: im going to sound stupid saying this but i followed a tutorial and i  know i followed it perfectly but it doesnt work. its meant to be the result for whether you have enough cash to buy a pet or not. but otherwise im unsure.

Comment: no need to worry about sounding stupid, following a tutorial is a great way to learn. Can you add a link to the tutorial to your question

Comment: its at about 40 mins

Comment: could you find the issue on the video?

Comment: please don't expect us to watch a 1.5 hour youtube video... post your code as text. even if you followed a tutorial it is you who created those instances, so you should know why that value is nil. `script.Parent.Parent` is nil because `script.Parent` so find out where you created `script.Parent` and check why there is no parent.

Comment: sorry piglet. another person told me to put the link. it wasnt meant so you had to watch it. again, my bad